# Slicing dataframes with varying conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

Let's suppose we have this reproducible dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [20,15,34,40,60],
    'rank': [2, 7, 6, 5, 1],
    'height':[155, 159, 180 , 163, 170],
    'weight':[53, 60, 75, 80, 49],
                  })
```

I'm trying to slice this dataframe based on pre-defined conditions, where each condition is a list like this [[threshold_value,name_of_column], [threshold_value2 ,name_of_column_2], ...]. These are the following conditions:

```
#Conditions:
condition_1 = [[16,'age'],[8,'rank'], [163, 'height']]
condition_2 = [[25,'age'], [60, 'weight'] ,[5,'rank']]
condition_3 = [[50,'age'], [3, 'rank']]
```

Is there a way to slice the dataframe with each combination of conditions correspondently ? (using pandas.query() or any slicing method)

I am able to do so but manually for each condition, something like this:

```
#Expected output:
output_df_1 = df[ (df['age'] < 16) & (df['rank'] < 8) & (df['height'] < 163)]
output_df_2 = df[ (df['age'] < 25) & (df['weight'] < 60) & (df['rank'] < 5)]
output_df_3 = df[ (df['age'] < 50) & (df['rank'] < 3)]
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated, thank you !

Comment: I don't recommend `foo_1`, `foo_2`, `foo_3`, `foo_n`. Use a list instead and use it like `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`, `foo[2]`. This goes for both input and output -- it'll be pretty much unusable otherwise, I'd think. Once you have this, just loop over the list of conditions, and for each condition, loop over the constraints and apply each one and append the filtered result df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [30]: import pandas as pd
In [31]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'age': [20,15,34,40,60],
    ...:     'rank': [2, 7, 6, 5, 1],
    ...:     'height':[155, 159, 180 , 163, 170],
    ...:     'weight':[53, 60, 75, 80, 49],
    ...:                   })
In [32]: condition_1 = [[16,'age'],[8,'rank'], [163, 'height']]
In [33]: df[ (df['age'] < 16) & (df['rank'] < 8) & (df['height'] < 163)]
Out[33]: 
   age  rank  height  weight
1   15     7     159      60
In [34]: (df['age'] < 16) & (df['rank'] < 8) & (df['height'] < 163)
Out[34]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

We could use a list comprehension to apply the tests, and `logical_and.reduce` to combine them:

```
In [37]: np.logical_and.reduce([df[col]<val for val,col in condition_1])
Out[37]: array([False,  True, False, False, False])
In [38]: df[np.logical_and.reduce([df[col]<val for val,col in condition_1])]
Out[38]: 
   age  rank  height  weight
1   15     7     159      60
```

Or we could apply the tests to an array version of the frame.  This is an example of `numpy vectorization`.

rearrange `condition_1`:

```
In [39]: values, cols = zip(*condition_1)
In [40]: values
Out[40]: (16, 8, 163)
In [41]: cols
Out[41]: ('age', 'rank', 'height')
```

The desired columns as array:

```
In [43]: df[list(cols)]
Out[43]: 
   age  rank  height
0   20     2     155
1   15     7     159
2   34     6     180
3   40     5     163
4   60     1     170
In [44]: df[list(cols)].values
Out[44]: 
array([[ 20,   2, 155],
       [ 15,   7, 159],
       [ 34,   6, 180],
       [ 40,   5, 163],
       [ 60,   1, 170]])
```

apply the test:

```
In [45]: df[list(cols)].values<values
Out[45]: 
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]])
```

(bad choice of `values` variable in [39]).  This applies `<` to a (n,3) and (3,), which works by `broadcasting`.

and find the `row` that is True for all values - same as [37]

```
In [51]: (df[list(cols)].values<values).all(axis=1)
Out[51]: array([False,  True, False, False, False])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do all of those &s separately:

```
pick = np.ones[df.shape[0]]
for value,key in condition_1:
    pick = pick & (df[key] < value)
```

You then use that column of booleans to extract the rows you want, just as you did in your example.

```
output = df[pick]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the first line ? Can't I just do all = df.copy() or create an empty df ?

Comment: How can I return a df with values instead of boolean expressions ?

Comment: You then use the list of booleans to extract the rows:  `df[pick]`